# Disable basic auth only on subpaths

Tags: nginx

What is wrong with the below configuration? I just wanted to enable auth for 
/main and disable it for /main/public  . The below configuration enables it for both the paths.

I tried changing certain configuration like moving /main/public outside. but it didn't work.

```
location ^~ /main {
    location ^~ /main/public {
        auth_basic off;
        alias /var/www/main/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @main-frontend;
    }
    auth_basic "Storybook";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;

    alias /var/www/main/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @main-frontend;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: both main and main/public  shows password screen

Comment: Is `@main-frontend` password protected? And where are the files? Should you be using `alias` or `root`?

Comment: @main-frontend is not password protected.  alias worked fine earlier before I added basic auth.